# Darkness Spell for Drow. How many times can I use it before rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, racial-traits

Because this is an innate spell given, is there a number of times that I can use it before I have to take a short or long rest? Using only once seems a bit odd.

Comment: Oh dear... Three identical answers within 30 seconds. I wonder what the protocol for this situation is.

Comment: @Ladifas No protocol. That's what voting is for.

Comment: [Related] [Can you cast a racial spell if you do not have access to the spell slot required?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68809)

Answer (score 14):

### Once per long rest as racial trait.

When you are level 5 or above you can use the darkness spell once per long rest as racial trait.

If your class allows you to cast darkness, you can do so with your spell slots.

The racial trait:

> [...] When you reach 5th level, you can
> also cast the darkness spell once per day. [...]

There was an [errata](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PH-Errata-V1.pdf) which says the following

> **Drow Magic (p. 24).** 
> Here “once per day” means you must finish a long rest to
> cast the spell again with the trait.

Comment: The second printing (August 2014) of the PH, p.24, includes this updated language: "When you reach 5th level, you can cast the *darkness* spell once with this trait [Drow Magic] and regain the ability to do so when you finish a long rest."

Answer (score 6):

### Once per Long Rest

The [Player's Handbook Errata](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PH-Errata-V1.pdf) clarifies this, reading:

> **Drow Magic (p. 24).** Here “once per day” means you must finish a long rest to cast the spell again with the trait

This is a point that has come up across all three books, where 'once per day' has almost universally been clarified to mean 'once per long rest'.

Somewhat frustratingly, errata, and other rules clarifications are lumped in with all other announcements in the [features](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features) section of the D&D part of the WotC website.

Answer (score 5):

It does says you get to use it only once per day, and that's it:

> ***Drow Magic.*** … When you reach 5th level, you can also cast the *darkness* spell once per day.

The [errata for the PHB](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf) clarifies further that “once per day” means only once between long rests.